# Select descendants, except of one child

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Let’s say I have this HTML:

```
<div class="par">
  <div class="s1">
    <a href="#" class="s1">link</link>
  </div>
  <div class="s8">
    <a href="#" class="s1">link</link>
    <div class="s1">
      <a href="#" class="s1">link</link>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="ds44">
    <a href="#" class="s1">link</link>
  </div>
  <span class="t">This is text</span>
  <div class="thisOne">
    <a href="#" class="s1">link</link>
  </div>
</div>
```

now I want to call this function:

```
function aFn(){
  alert('Omid');
}
```

by clicking on any elements in `<div class="par">` except `<div class="thisOne">` and its children. How can I do that?

Comment: What have you tried so far? Can you share with us the code that you might have tried at your end?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Handle `click` on `.par` and check `e.target`.

For example,

```
$(".par").on("click", function(e) {
    if ($(e.target).closest(".thisOne").length) {
        return;
    }

    …
});
```

[Okay, that worked.](http://jsfiddle.net/minitech/zzY8Q/1/)

Comment: but there is an element in `.thisOne` and that element rising click event !

Comment: @OMiD: It’s the child combinator – it means to look for `.thisOne`s that are direct descendants of `.par`.

Comment: @OMiD: Um, hold on to whatever worked. I’m trying some things

Comment: I want to select, your previous answer was exactly what I'm looking for

Comment: Damn it, what the hell is wrong with your previous answer ? I DONT WANT TO USE `return;` for nothing ! I want optimize my codes and stop writing useless codes like `if($(e.target).closest(".thisOne").length)` this code fires 2 functions and one if statement and then return for nothing !

Comment: @OMiD: Do you understand how this code works? It’s actually more efficient, and “returning nothing” is not “useless”.

Comment: return nothing is useless when we select some unwanted elements and track them then find them and then skip them ! do you even know `$()` is a function and this function doing a lot of codes ? and do you know `.closest()` is a function too and these 2 functions taking time for parsing codes ? and `if` is statement ! why we should select some unwanted elements and then skip them ?

Comment: @OMiDL Because you’re not selecting unwanted elements, but it’s moot, because my old answer didn’t work… did it? Well, if it did work for you, I can change it back, I suppose. I just tried it and it didn’t seem to…

Answer (score 2):

Assign a click handler to `.par`, then assign one to `.thisOne` that prevents the click from bubbling to `.par`.

```
$('.par').click(aFn);

$('.thisOne').click(function(e) {
    e.stopPropagation();
});
```

Comment: this is not what i'm looking for ! i want to select ! not rising a function, and thank to @minitech it's working now

Comment: `aFn` will be called by clicking on `.par` or its children, except `.thisOne` and it's children. Isn't that what you wanted?

Comment: It's working but my html has alot of object they shouldn'd selecet, and if i select them, my application working slowly !!